# Trying to return rows based on condition of summed columns

Tags: sql, rmysql

Apologies if this has been asked. For what I thought was a relatively simple question, I couldn't seem to find the answer in my searches.

linesInserted and linesDeleted are two columns in the table. I'm trying to return rows where linesInserted + linesDeleted >= 200. The query I have is

```
SELECT *, (linesInserted + linesDeleted) as total
FROM table
WHERE total >= 200
GROUP BY id
```

This doesn't work as I'm getting an error saying:

```
Unknown column 'TOTAL' in where clause
```

I'm using RMySql for those curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you sum over `linesInserted + linesDeleted` then there would be no problem:

```
SELECT id, sum(linesInserted + linesDeleted) as total
FROM table
GROUP BY id
having total >= 200
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
SELECT id, sum(linesInserted + linesDeleted) as total
FROM table
GROUP BY id
having sum(linesInserted + linesDeleted)>=200
```

Answer (score 0):

Here sum is an aggregate function, so we couldn't use where to check the condition as the total is greater than or equal to 200. We should use the having to check the condition since we use sum to calculate the values.